# Fetching a user's current Facebook status with OmniAuth & Rails

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, omniauth

As you may have guessed from the title, I'm trying to use OmniAuth to get my users' current Facebook statuses (for a new opt-in feature). I've passed the necessary scope option into the provider method, inside the omniauth initializer. I know that's a mouthful, sorry. This code should help:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], { scope: 'user_status' }
end
```

I know that part works, because during the OAuth dialogue, Facebook prompts the user to allow access to their status message. So, the problem is I'm expecting their status to be returned in the Auth Hash, with the rest of the user info, but it's just not there.

```
def callback
  raise request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml
end
```

Yes, that's oversimplified, but I figure you don't care about my before_filters etc.

I've googled around for about 2hrs now, and all of the examples that I found were really contrived. The ones that covered scope only mentioned how to request permission, but not how to actually get the data.

There was [a similar unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268395/how-do-i-get-facebook-profile-data-from-an-omniauth-login-request) here on SO, but it's so old, that I didn't think it was a good idea to resurrect it.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

---

**July 3rd Update:**

Thanks for your help! I've taken your advice and used the token from the auth hash to request the user's current status like so:

```
FbGraph::User.me(@auth[:credentials][:token]).posts.first.message
```

**For future readers:** It's important to note that the token expires in about 2 months time, and every time the user changes their password. You *may* want to notify your users when their token is close to expiration. From what I could glean in the FB docs, the expiration date is expressed in the form of a **Unix Timestamp**. You can convert that to something more useful to like a **Ruby DateTime** like so:

```
expires_at = Time.at(@auth[:credentials][:expires_at]).to_datetime
```

Then, you can save the token in your model and call **past?** on it to make sure your app doesn't try to use invalid tokens.

```
do_something unless expires_at.past?
```

Comment: hi, i am having the same problem. trying to go through fbk permissions reference http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ (under user_status). having no luck yet!

Answer (score 2):

When you set the `user_status` permission (and the user approves it), Facebook grants your application access to read that user's status messages. No user status messages are going to be returned in the authentication process, you have to issue a separate call to retrieve the user's status updates.

After your app is granted permission, you could use a gem like [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) to make subsequent requests to Facebook. Here's an example of how you could integrate this with OmniAuth:

```
user = FbGraph::User.new('me', :access_token => session[:omniauth]["credentials"]["token"])
user.fetch
```

Other gems that you could utilize would be [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) and [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2). [Here's an example](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2010/4/22/oauth2-gem-just-in-time-for-facebook-graph) of using oauth2 w/ Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the status (stati) is not returned as a part of auth hash. You have to request this after you have the token.
For example (using koala gem):

```
api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(auth.credentials.token)
api.get_connections('me', 'statuses').first
```

You can check it using the Graph explorer:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fstatuses

Comment: I guess I just expected it to be there, because twitter puts it in their auth hash. It's not really easy to get at, but it's under raw_data, and you can parse it with JSON.